# Add Tables As A Field In Django Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite, foreign-keys

So I Am Making A Shop Website I wanted to ask how do we add tables as a field? Do we use foreign key or something in Django I am using SQLite btw

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Y5H.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use model fields as table fields. Basically, you require ORM(Object-relational mapping). I am adding a basic model snippet below with a foreign key added.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # This for foreign key .The plus sign means that a reverse relation won't be created!
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey('Product',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='+')

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='-')
    description = models.TextField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this works? Also is it possible to make it so when I create my Product object I also want it to create a size object and I want the size object to be modified directly from the product object from django admin?

Comment: ORM basically mapps your class to db. They both with share common charecterestics. Please search how ORM works to learn details.Hard for me to explain from just comments. And to answer your last question.Yes, you can modify it from django admin

Comment: Do I Use One To One Field Or Foreign Keys With Unique = True? I Cant Use Many To Many Fields Because Same Dress Cant Have Different Size Models